# Examples of Google Cloud Storage Used With Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Anybody have any code examples for using google cloud storage with google app engine(python)?

The best I've seen so far is from an answer I received from a prior question I posted: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/demo/main.py

However, the code seems to run successfully regardless of the connection and I can't seem to find the files in my GCS bucket

Comment: http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/resource/upload/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.py this script is uploading directly to GCS, by altering the the create_upload_url function and removing gb_bucket_name it will use the blob store.

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name='bucket_name')
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
    self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
        name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form

    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                               ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Just tried this and didn't show up in the GCS bucket. Based on the examples I'm seeing, there seem to be some additional config needed but not too sure. Ran the sample code in the link following and the file doesn't show up in the GCS console either even after I get rid of the final delete... also it doesn't exactly do an upload: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage